# Function not known while iterating LINQ to Entities result set

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-6

When I execute this query, then try and iterate it's results, I get the error below them:

```
Dim recs = MonitorContext.DataRecords.OrderBy(Function(dr) dr.INDEX).ThenBy(Function(dr) dr.TIMESTAMP). _
Where(Function(dr) dr.TYPE = If(type, dr.TYPE)). _
Where(Function(i) i.INDEX > 2 And i.INDEX < 8). _
Where(Function(dr) dr.INDEX >= If(startIndex, dr.INDEX) And dr.INDEX <= If(endIndex, dr.INDEX)). _
Where(Function(dr) dr.TIMESTAMP >= If(startTime, dr.TIMESTAMP))
```

The error occurs here:

```
For Each rec As DataRecord In recs.ToList()
```

The error is:

`EntityCommandExecutionException`:

> {"The specified argument value for the function is not valid. [
>   Argument # = 3,Name of function(if known) = case ]"}

My data record looks like this:

```
Public Class DataRecord
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property INDEX As Integer
    Public Property DeviceId As Integer
    Public Property TYPE As String
    Public Property TIMESTAMP As DateTime
    Public Property DI1 As Double
    Public Property DI2 As Double
    Public Property DI3 As Double
    Public Property DI4 As Double
    ...
    ...
    Public Property GSM As Double
    Public Property P As Double
    Public Property E As Double
    Public Property V As Double
    Public Property I As Double
End Class
```

Abridged of course. There are about twenty `Double` members that are legacy only and play no role.
I am brave enough to be doing this in VB.NET against a SqlCe database through EF 6.

Comment: Look at the generated sql, using the ToString method of recs, and grab it and run it directly against the database to find out what is going on

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the VB coalescing `If()` function was somehow being mistranslated. When I replaced

```
Where(Function(dr) If(startTime, dr.TIMESTAMP) >= startTime)
```

with

```
Where(Function(dr) startTime Is Nothing OrElse dr.TIMESTAMP >= startTime)
```

and all the other `Where` clauses that used `If()`, everything worked quite smoothly.